# SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' with WhatsApp API on Asp Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, whatsapp

I'm trying to send messages with WhatsApp API through my Asp Net program which is in a server, but the connection 'was forcibly closed by the remote host' when I try to make the POST.

The messages are sended correctly when I do this in the local machine, but in the server is impossible to make this POST.

I thought it could be the connection is being blocked by te Firewall, so I tried to allow all the connections via the port my program connects, and made a new Firewall rule, but nothing succeded.